# self signed certificate for a site that can only be access through VPN

Tags: vpn, openssl, certificate, self-signed-certificate

I read a lot of articles about self signed certificates and I'm not exactly sure if I'm getting near to what I want to actually achieve.

I'm trying to implement a self signed certificate so that the end users will not be seeing the "not secured warning" when they try to access the site (we are accessing the site through the company VPN). So, from what I understand is that the created certificate is needed to be imported to the machine's browsers for the end user not to see the "not secured warning".

Here's my dilemma, we've got hundreds of users that needed to use the site. Do we need to import the certificate on each machines browsers? Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> Do we need to import the certificate on each machines browsers?

Essentially correct, yes. This can be done with a management system, such as Active Directory.

> Or is there any other way to do this?

Get a proper signed trusted cert from e.g. LetsEncrypt.

Comment: In case of Let's Encrypt, the actual secured site itself needs not to be exposed to the Internet (one can use a DNS-01 challenge, or a "sibling and fake" public http server with the same DNS name whose only purpose would be to complete HTTP-01 challenge for that name); however, it's required to be accessed using a public registered DNS name (or at least, belong to a registered domain in case of DNS-01 challenge).

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov we are trying to do this in an intranet setup. Does Let's Encrypt will still work?

Comment: @ReefoRelaxo If you have a valid (public) DNS name for it. You can use the DNS-01 challenge to get the certificate, which will never reveal anything but the name to the outside world. If you don't have an internal PKI setup, this is the *best* way to handle things

Comment: And, the server you're going to use will need to connect to outside world — to Let's Encrypt (or ZeroSSL which provides similar service) to request a challenge/obtain certificate, and to your DNS hoster to complete the challenge, but itself it doesn't need to be accessible from the Internet, even indirectly. This is the benefit of DNS-01 challenge, which is worth additional complexity in a setup. Another benefit is that it allows you to request wildcard certificate.