# self signed for a site accessible through VPN

Tags: nginx, vpn, openssl, ubuntu-20.04, self-signed-certificate

I'd like to know if what I'm doing is right or is there another way to do this?

I have this site that is accessible through VPN and i'd like the end users not to see the "not secured" warning. And I made a self signed certificate for this site. But currently the end users who are not seeing the warning are those who have the certificate imported in their trust root. And we still have hundreds of users that needed to access this site.

Now, I tried uploading the pem and key in the VPN, but it didn't work.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/1143063/self-signed-certificate-for-a-site-that-can-only-be-access-through-vpn/1143068#comment1491066_1143068

Comment: You need to include *details* on what you did. Where did you upload it? How is things configured?